# Using Winasm create .inc , .lib with dll

Tags: assembly, dll, masm

I'm newbie in using Winasm.

I'm studying tut of Iczelion, in about DLL, I create .asm and .def file, but after assemble and link, only create .dll and .obj file

I don't know how to create .inc, .lib file (I need them because it needed in after).

How I can do can create .inc , .lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create .lib file in MASM ?

Steps bellow is create exe (dll) file from asm source file.

You do these command:

1. Set path:

   set path = path to bin directory in masm32
2. Compile:

   ml /c /coff <.asm file name>
3. Compile resouse (if needed):

   rc <.rc file name>

4a. Link and make .lib file (if you want to make .dll file):

```
link /DLL /DEF:<.def file name>.def /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS <.obj file name>     or
```

4b. Link and make .lib file (if you want to make .exe file):

```
link /DEF:<.def file name>.def /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS <.obj file name>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use link.exe with -DLL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

[On Iczelions tutorial page,](http://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/tutorials.html)
in the section "Other Tutorials by Iczelion"
Click on the link: [Hints on how to create MASM import lib](http://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/importlib.html)